# Adobe Reader - What is the shortcut to rotate clockwise?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-reader, german

- Win 7 64 bit
- Adobe Reader XI with shortcuts enabled (see Options Menu - General)
- German keyboard! (and of course a localized OS and so forth)

Official shortcut list by Adobe: http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/keyboard-shortcuts.html

The official shortcuts are shown when I hover the cursor over the buttons:

- **turn clockwise** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> (plus)
- **turn counter-clockwise** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (minus)

They are both not working for me. Instead I can only rotate counter-clockwise via this combination:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

**What is the shortcut to rotate clockwise then?**

Tried the following combination with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>:

- 2 to 0
- , (comma)
- . (dot)
- #
- `´`

Comment: For me, Win7, Adobe reader X, Ctrl+Shift+1 is not working. Click on View menu->Rotate view-> This gives the option to rotate clock and counter clock wise. Next to this the keyboard shortcut is mentioned. What is it in reader XI?

Comment: @Prasanna The ones I listed are shown. Edited the op in this regard.

Comment: For other reference: Ctrl + Shift + Plus, Ctrl + Shift + Minus work for me, Win 10 Home English, Acrobat X Pro Chinese

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so here is my take on this problem. I can recreate the issue by adding German keyboard layout. And I can confirm that using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> does not work when German layout is on.

What does work in my case is:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> = rotate clockwise
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> = rotate counterclockwise

*Note: I used German:Germany layout, not Austria,Switzerland or Luxembourg*

However <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> does not do anything in my case. And this makes me think that maybe actual keyboard controller on your German keyboard is behaving differently. Anyway - I would recommend you to first try all possible combinations involving <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Some Key</kbd> and if you have no luck with that try installing English:US layout and see whether that works

UPDATE:
I am using a laptop so I do not have dedicated num pad keys. I have figured out the option that works for me regardless of keyboard layout. I have num pad keys mapped accross the keyboad and accessable via <kbd>Fn</kbd>. Following combinations are valid:

- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> = Numpad:<kbd>-</kbd>
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> = Numpad:<kbd>+</kbd>

Having that said, following combinations work in Adobe reader regardless the layout. I have tested with German, English and Russian:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> = rotate counterclockwise
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> = rotate clockwise

So I recommend you to experiment with your numpad for better results.

Comment: What?  You tested this with German, English, and Russian?  You deserve some upvoting just for putting in such effort.

Answer (score 0):

In my case following shortcuts worked

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to rotate right

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to rotate left

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Although these *are* the default shortcuts, the original question states that this keyboard combination does not work for them.